# Flask REST POST request failing "Bad Request" based on length of json

Tags: java, json, rest, flask, httpclient

I'm running into an issue where I am making posts to a flask app and receiving a flask page response: Bad Request the browser or proxy sent a request that this server could not understand.

For some useful details...

```
    String testjsonstr = "["+jsonList.get(0).toString()+","+jsonList.get(1).toString()+","+jsonList.get(2).toString()+"]";
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(testjsonstr);
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

fails to post and gives the mentioned 'bad request'

editing the json string to

```
 String testjsonstr = "["+jsonList.get(0).toString()+","+jsonList.get(1).toString()+"]";
```

results in a successful post. I've tested this and any combination of 2 items from jsonList work. When I try to add a third item to the json list I get the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Flask logs and source code the POST handler would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for checking it! Not sure what happened or if I was just using bad data but I tried with a new list of jsonObjects and it seems to work which means it's a data issue i guess... there are no flask errors in my server log that give me any idea what's wrong with the request that I can see and it's driving me crazy. In any case I should be able to fiddle around with the data until it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it there were non breaking spaces in the json data utf-8 was listed as C2A0.